# Is this regex syntax working?

Tags: python, regex

I wanted to search a string for a substring beginning with ">"
Does this syntax say what I want it to say: this character followed by anything.

```
regex_firstline = re.compile("[>]{1}.*")
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you test it?

Comment: this yould only tell you, if a `>` character came before any other thing. So it would match this: "hello > test" as well.

Comment: That's pretty much the most complicated way you could have written it, too; consider taking a tutorial.

Comment: A `substring` is what you want to search for beginning with less than character. That character is not (regex) special. Inside classes, those special characters lose that meaning. No need for the class, but it doesn't hurt. The rest of it `.*` has no ending, it will optionally match the remaining string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a pythonic way for such tasks you can use [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) method, and don't need to use regex.

But about your regex `"[>]{1}.*"` you don't need `{1}` after your character class and you can specify the start of your regex with anchor `^`.So it can be `"^>.*"`

Answer (score 0):

Using http://regex101.com:

- `[>]{1}` matches the single character `>` literally exactly one time (but it denotes `{1}` is a meaningless quantifier), and
- `.*` then matches any character as many times as possible.

If a list was provided inside square brackets (as opposed to a single character), regex would attempt to match a single character within the list exactly one time. http://regex101.com has a good listing of tokens and what they mean.

An ideal regex expression would be `^[>].*`, meaning at the beginning of a string find exactly one `>` character followed by anything else (and with only one character in the square brackets, you can remove those to simplify it even further: `^>.*`